# Why doesn't [[]] == list(list())

Tags: python, list

I just randomly observed the following in Python and am curious to know the reason why this evaluates to `False`:

```py
list(list()) == [[]]
```

Interestingly if you rearrange the syntax in the following ways, the first way evaluates as `False`, but the second as `True`:

```py
list([]) == [[]]
[list()] == [[]]
```

What is going on under the hood here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the the [Python 2 documentation on the `list` constructor](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-list)

> *class* **list**([*iterable*])
>
> > Return a list whose items are the same and in the same order as *iterable*’s items. *iterable* may be either a sequence, a container that supports iteration, or an iterator object. If *iterable* is already a list, a copy is made and returned, similar to `iterable[:]`. For instance, `list('abc')` returns `['a', 'b', 'c']` and `list( (1, 2, 3) )` returns `[1, 2, 3]`. If no argument is given, returns a new empty list, `[]`.

When you pass a `list` to `list()` it returns a copy, not a nested list, whereas `[[]]` creates an empty nested list - or rather a list containing a single element which is itself an empty list.

---

**Note**   -   This is notably absent from the corresponding [Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list), but it holds true for Python 3 regardless.

Answer (score 9):

`list` does not construct a list that contains its argument; it constructs a list whose elements are contained in its argument. `list([])` does not return `[[]]`; it returns `[]`. Thus, `list(list()) == list([]) == []`.

Answer (score 6):

`list(...)` constructor is not doing the same thing as the list literal `[...]`. The [constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) takes any *iterable* and makes a list out of its items

```
>>> list((1, 2, 3))
[1, 2, 3]
>>> list("foo")
['f', 'o', 'o']
>>> list(list())
```

whereas a list literal defines a list with exactly the enumerated items

```
>>> [(1, 2, 3)]
[(1, 2, 3)]
>>> ["foo"]
['foo']
>>> [[]]
[[]]
```

Note that when called without any arguments, `list()` produces the same result as `[]`.

Answer (score 3):

When you do `list(list())` you are creating a list and convert it to a list on the fly. Therefore, you end up with a single empty list, not a nested list.

Comment: In other words the `list` constructor takes an iterable (producing an empty list if non is supplied) so `list(list())` = `list([])` = `list()` = `[]`